# HiveQL: Divide all values of a column by max of the column

Tags: hive, hiveql

How do you divide all values of a column by the max of the column?

For example, suppose I have:

```
id value
1  10
2  20
3  30
```

I want:

```
id value
1  0.33333
2  0.66666
3  0.99999
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT col_a/MAX(col_a)
FROM db.table
```

and

```
SELECT col_a/(SELECT MAX(col_a) FROM db.table)
FROM db.table
```

and both attempts failed with lengthy error messages.

While I was able to get the code of the first answer below to work when I copy-pasted it, I couldn't replicate its results with my own table. I tried:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT * FROM mydb.tablenamehere)
SELECT colA/MAX(colA) OVER()
FROM temp;
```

and also:

```
USE mydb;
WITH temp AS (SELECT * FROM tablenamehere)
SELECT colA/MAX(colA) OVER()
FROM temp;
```

but I get the following error for both:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:28 Table not found 'tablenamehere' in definition of CTE temp [
SELECT * FROM tablenamehere
] used as temp at Line 1:28
```

Comment: does table  mydb.tablenamehere really exist?

Comment: yes, it does exist.

Comment: You don't need that temp CTE.  Just try something more simple like this `SELECT value/MAX(value) OVER()
FROM db.table;`

Comment: The problem is that I have an `id` column. So I'd need to do:

`SELECT id, value/MAX(value) FROM db.table GROUP BY id` which returns the following error: `Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.`

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic `max()`:

```
with your_table as ( --use your table instead of this
select stack(3,
1,  10 ,
2,  20 ,
3,  30 ) as (id, value)
)

select id, value/max(value) over() as value 
  from your_table
order by id --remove order if not necessary
;
```

Returns:

```
OK
1       0.3333333333333333
2       0.6666666666666666
3       1.0
Time taken: 80.474 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Comment: I tried your code. It worked. I couldn't apply it to my own code though. More details added to my original post.